# How can I set the state in a static react function?

Tags: reactjs

I have a notification-class, the notification-message shall be set from outsiede. Now it complians that this.setState is not defined. How can I fix this?

React:

```
const Notification = React.createClass({

  statics: {
    createAlert: function(message) {
      this.setState({message: message});
    }
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        message: '',
    };
  },
```

Comment: How are you calling that method? Its likely that the `this` is something other than what you expect.

Comment: I call it from another react-class. I actually want to address the "this" of the notification-class

Comment: I think that is an antipattern. I think you want to set a `prop`?

Comment: I want the notification-container in the main-react-class and set the notification-message from other react-classes nested in the main-react-class.

Answer (score 1):

Statics don't have instances. That's the whole point of statics, i.e they are shared between classes so having a `this` context won't work. You shouldn't be doing this with statics. I only use ES6 syntax so this might be syntactically wrong.

```
const Notification = React.createClass({
    setMessage: function(message) {
        this.setState({message: message});
    }
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            message: '',
        };
    }
    render: function() {
        return (
            //Pass the setMessage function as a prop to a child class
            //You will need to .bind() setMessage somewhere
            <ChildClass setMessage={this.setMessage} /> 
        )
    }
});

const ChildClass = React.createClass({

    doSomething: function() {
        this.props.setMessage("Hello");
    }
    render: function() {
        return (

        )
    }
});
```

If the child class is nested multiple levels deep then use a state management like redux, flux or you can use React's context.